# CSS Tooltip on mobile devices won't close on second press

Tags: css

I have the following code:

**code:**

```
<div id="A" class="tooltip">
<img style="border-bottom: 1px dotted black;"  src="some image.jpg" /> 
        <span class="tooltiptext">My hover over text</span>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.tooltip {position: relative; display: inline-block;}
.tooltip .tooltiptext { visibility: hidden;  width: 400px;  background-color: lightgray;  color: #000; font-size: 15px;font-weight: 100;  text-align: left;  border-radius: 6px;  padding: 5px;  position: absolute;  z-index: 1;  top: -5px;  right: 115%;    left: auto;    margin-left: 0px; }
.tooltip .tooltiptext::after { content: "";  position: absolute;    bottom: auto;  top: 50%;  left: 100%;  margin-top: -10px;  border-width: 10px; border-style: solid;border-color: transparent transparent transparent lightgrey;}
.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {  visibility: visible;}
```

Which works fine on a desktop when you hover over the image, however when pressed on a mobile device it will not disappear. Is there a way to make that work with CSS.
Any help welcome

Answer (score 0):

Hover handling is highly mobile-browser-specific. Most browsers will either show the :hover state before navigating away, or permanently on long-tap. The only way to hide it is to long-tap somewhere else AFAIK. JS may be needed with a timeout-based solution.

Answer (score 0):

What it needs to toggle on a mobile device is the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(
        function() {
            $("#A").click(function() {
                $("#Text_A").toggle();
            });
        });

    </script> 

<div id="A" class="tooltip">
<img id= "Text_A" style="border-bottom: 1px dotted black;"  src="some image.jpg" /> 
        <span class="tooltiptext">My hover over text</span>
</div>
```

This worked for me the CSS is not changed